# core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'idPersona' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

soy nuevo en Angular y estoy haciendo un curso y me quedé atascado a la hora de modificar un objeto. En el curso el código le funciona correctamente, pero a mi me da el siguiente error a la hora de modificar el nombre de una persona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo persona-service.ts tengo este error de compilación, que lo puedo solucionar poniendo "?" al final, pero a la hora de intentar modificar un archivo no me funciona. Y estuve indagando en la red, pero no acabo de encontrar lo que está fallando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna ayuda de donde puede estar el problema?

Comparto el repositorio público del frontend:
https://github.com/leoag81/personas-front-angular

Los datos los obtiene de un webservice en java.

**(08/01/2021) EDICIÓN DE LA PREGUNTA:**

Modifiqué este método:

```
encontrarPersona(id: number){
    console.log('id persona :' + id);
    // console.log('persona 0: ' + this.personas[0]);
    const resultado: Persona | undefined = this.personas.find( persona => persona.idPersona === id);
    if (resultado) {
        console.log('persona encontrada:' + resultado.idPersona + ' ' + resultado.nombre);
      } else{
        console.log('No se encontró a la persona');
      }
    return resultado;
}
```

Y obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque no me encuentra la persona si ese id existe en los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El array de personas lo inicio aqui:

```
  // definimos un array para las personas
  personas: Persona[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

  // La llamada al DataService es Asincrona, por lo que tenemos que inicializar el arreglo persona
  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  setPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
    this.personas = personas;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el método `this.personas.find` puede devolver *Persona* o no devolver nada, *undefined*. Por un lado, deberías cambiar el tipo de *resultado*:

```
const resultado: Persona | undefined = ...
```

Por otro lado, deberías verificar si has obtenido un resultado antes de trabajar con él:

```
if (resultado) {
...
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, edité la pregunta, ya no me da error, pero no me encuentra el id en el array de personas

Comment: Si es una llamada asíncrona, tiene pinta de que aún no has cargado el resultado en personas. Te recomiendo que pongas un console.log con la longitud del arreglo en el método encontrarPersona y traces el por qué no se ha cargado aún, quizás no estés usando correctamente Promise. En cualquier caso, considero que deberías marcar esta respuesta como válida si te ha resuelto el problema inicial y abras una nueva con la nueva casuística a resolver.